# Sylvester Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't find the proof of this anywhere:

> If $A,B\in End(V)$ then we have $\dim ker(AB) \leq \dim ker(A)+ \dim ker(B)$.

My prof says that the map $ker(AB)\to ker(A), x\mapsto Bx$ is surjective and that $ker(B)$ is contained in its kernel. This gives the claim, but I don't see why that map is surjective. *So, why is it surjective*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it isn't surjective: $A = B = 0$ is a counterexample to that. On the other hand, the kernel of the map $x \mapsto Bx$, even when restricted to $\mathrm{ker}(AB)$, is exactly $\mathrm{ker}(B)$ (as any element with $Bx = 0$ is already in $\mathrm{ker}(AB)$ anyway).

To prove this, use the rank-nullity theorem which gives you $$\mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{ker}(AB) = \mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{ker}(B) + \mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{im}\Big(\mathrm{ker}(AB) \rightarrow \mathrm{ker}(B), \; x \mapsto Bx \Big)$$ $$\le \mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{ker}(B) + \mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{ker}(A),$$ since $\mathrm{im}\Big(\mathrm{ker}(AB) \rightarrow \mathrm{ker}(B), \; x \mapsto Bx \Big)$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{ker}(A).$

Comment: The first equality is an inequality, no?

Comment: @rehband No. Dimension of starting space = dimension of kernel + dimension of image.

Comment: thanks, why is the kernel of the map $ker(AB)\to ker(B)$ equal to the kernel of $B$?

Comment: @rehband You're just looking for elements $v$ with $Bv = 0$. Any such element is automatically in $\mathrm{ker}(AB)$ so you get the whole kernel of $B$.

Comment: ok thank u, user